# Control center bug on iPhone

Tags: iphone, bug, control-center

I have an iPhone 6 Plus.

There is a fairly recurring display bug concerning the AirDrop/AirPlay area in control center. Sometimes it appears squished, so that only a few pixels of it is visible. Whatever is there can still be tapped.

Screenshot:

[image: Display bug in control center of iPhone]

Is this a known bug? How can this be fixed?

Comment: I have seen that on my iPhone 6. Try rebooting your device.

Comment: My memory is good but short but I think I often saw the same error while on iPhone 5 and iOS 7.

Comment: It's interesting that you see it often. I have seen it, but the instance has been rare. The reality is, I don't think it is anything *other* then a bug.

Comment: I don't see it always, but very often. Like at this moment, it's still there. Yes it's a bug, and as said no data loss or security kind of bug so in reality it should not matter much, but still it happens so often that it's weird that Apple won't fix these things. Somewhere, it's annoying to see it so often...

Comment: Make sure you're updated to the latest version of iOS. This may fix your problem.

Comment: I haven't seen this problem for a long time so I guess it's fixed by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should have been resolved, try updating to the latest iOS version in Settings or restarting your device.